# Did Elvis Presley ever tip a limo driver with a limo?

Tags: celebrities

As always, Facebook makes for easy skeptics' fodder.

[image]

> Elvis Presley once asked his limo driver, "Do you own this limo or do you work for the company?" He responded, "I work for the company." Elvis said "Well, you own it now." The limo driver's tip was the limo.

The "source" mentioned in the image doesn't have [any results](http://unbelievablefactsblog.com/search/elvis) when I search for "Elvis", and all of the info I do find there doesn't actually show any sources for any of their claims.

Did this happen?

For bonus points, what was the resolution? (Did the limo company agree to sell the limo to Elvis to gift to the driver, etc?)

Answer (score 7):

A possible source for this is probably [Larry King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_King), the TV host. On an episode of [Larry King Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_King_Live) aired on Jan 14, 2005, he [relates the following anecdote](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/0501/14/lkl.01.html):

> *KING*: We'll ask in a minute what you each think might have been his strangest habit. Quick Elvis Presley story. **I never met Elvis, but met Colonel Parker.** Elvis Presley worked in Miami Beach once, at the Miami Beach Convention Center. He flew into Miami International Airport, a helicopter brought him over to Miami Beach at the helipad. A limo picked him up at the helipad and drove him 10 blocks to the convention center, where he performed. He got back in the limo to go back to the helicopter. When he got back to the helicopter, he said to the limo driver, "do you own this limo or do you work for the company?" And he said, "I work for the company." And he said, "you now own it." The limo driver's tip was the limo. We'll be right back.

Larry King appears to suggest that he got this story off [Colonel Tom Parker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonel_Tom_Parker), Elvis' manager.

I have no idea if the driver eventually got the limo.

Comment: Is this an answer, or just a repeat of the claim?

Comment: @Oddthinking I think it's evidence related to the claim ... and acceptable because it's "better" than the evidence questioned in the OP, because this answer at least names the source. Also the poster in the OP says that the "source is mentioned in our blog" however [when I look](http://unbelievablefactsblog.com/post/110665072952/elvis-presley-once-asked-his-limo-driver-do-you-own) I only see there a repeat of the claim, and no "source" for the claim.